# Como mudar o esquema default do postgresql no persistence.xml em uma aplicação java

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e estou com uma certa dificuldade de mudar o esquema default da aplicação. estou utilizando o PostgreSQL em uma aplicação Java com JPA e Hibernate como implementação.

`persistence.xml`

```
<persistence-unit name="comunicaVisual" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>entys.Pessoa</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1" />

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
            value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Quero colocar a aplicação ao invés do esquema *public* padrão colocada como outro nome por exemplo

```
<property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres/dremcom_drem" />
```

porém não estou tendo sucesso com as tentativas dessa forma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que faltou voce configurar a propriedade que lida com a seleção do esquema

seria algo do tipo

```
<property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="myschema"/>
```

Dependendo do caso, eventualmente você pode precisar fazer esta configuração usando a tag
     persistence-unit-metadata. Dá uma olhada nesta outra questão aqui do SO mesmo que fala sobre isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211138/jpa-eclipselink-how-to-change-default-schema

Neste caso o seu procedimento seria algo assim:

1) Crie um arquivo chamado orm.xml, salve-o na mesma pasta onde está o seu persistence.xml e adicione nele o seguinte conteúdo

```
<entity-mappings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <schema>NOME_DO_SEU_SCHEMA</schema>
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>   
</entity-mappings>
```

2) Modifique o conteudo de  do seu persistence.xml para referenciar o orm.xml, mais ou menos assim:

```
<persistence-unit name="comunicaVisual" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

 <mapping-file>orm.xml</mapping-file>   
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
 <class>entys.Pessoa</class>
     <!--- restante das configuraçoes seguem aqui -->

</persistence-unit>
```

3) Faça o deploy e teste a aplicação novamente

Uma última hipótese seria setar o nome do schema via annotations na propria entidade, mas isso é meio desnecessário no caso da tua aplicação fazer acesso a apenas uma base de dados

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sua-tablea", schema = "nome-do-schema")
```